# Is it possible to create a SNS subscription with CloudFormation without creating a topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create a 'Subscription' resource in a AWS CloudFormation JSON template without creating a new `AWS::SNS::Topic`?

In my case, the topic is created outside of the CloudFormation script, and I would like to create some subscriptions to it, involving resources created within the script.

I.E.

```or-tag-here
   "DbfExtractQueue": {
        "Type": "AWS::SQS::Queue"
    },

    "EtlSubscription": {
        "Type": "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
        "Properties": {
            "Endpoint": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["DbfExtractQueue", "Arn"] },
            "Protocol": "sqs",
            "TopicArn": { "Ref": "EtlNotificationTopicARN" }
        }
    },
```

The EtlNotificationTopicARN is passed into the script and represents a SNS topic ARN.

Comment: This is Observer pattern 101: the Subject should not know anything about the Observers. The fact that CloudFormation doesn't support it makes me roll my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already discovered, [AWS CloudFormation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) doesn't provide the expected `AWS::SNS::Subscription` resource (yet) and I'm not aware of this being possible by any other means, unfortunately - guess the rationale is that both are either managed within a template or externally, but your use case is sound and I can see no fundamental reason why this shouldn't be available (maybe they'll add it at some point, AWS is usually expanding their APIs over time to address such inconsistencies/missings).

Comment: Ok cool, thanks for the confirmation. I ended up using some ruby API calls to connect the queue to the topic, but like you said, it would be good to see in there at some point. cheers!

Answer (score 15):

It is now possible to do this directly in native CloudFormation as of November 2016:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sns-subscription.html

Samples from the above documentation.

YAML:

```
MySubscription:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
  Properties:
    Endpoint: test@email.com
    Protocol: email
    TopicArn: !Ref 'MySNSTopic'
```

JSON:

```
"MySubscription" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
  "Properties" : {
    "Endpoint" : "test@email.com",
    "Protocol" : "email",
    "TopicArn" : {"Ref" : "MySNSTopic"}
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to set rawMessageDelivery on the subscription you are out of luck I guess since there is no way to specify it when creating the subscription and the resource does not return its arn to be able to set it afterwards. Seems like the only way is using a custom lambda function for it if you want to use rawMessageDelivery. Are you aware of any way without using a custom lambda function?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible now since CloudFormation supports Custom Resource Types with Lambda functions.